# Select a specific value in Access using SQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am working on a project that links Access to a Java GUI. I am currently looking for a way to select a record, in a query, that contains a specific value.

If my fields are:

```
Name |      Job      | Hours Worked
Tom  | Sales Support |       6
Bill |    Manager    |       8
Tom  |  Sales Floor  |       5
```

and I enter Tom in a search field in the GUI, I would like it to return the following to the GUI:

```
Name |      Job      | Hours Worked
Tom  | Sales Support |       6
Tom  |  Sales Floor  |       5
```

I tried using this code:

```
       ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
       String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Bob\\Schedule.accdb";
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+filePath);
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [Double Booking] WHERE [Name] = Tom");
       while(rs.next()) list.add(rs.getString(1));
       con.close();
       return list.toArray();
```

but I get the error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TOM
```

When I enter st.executeQuery("SELECT [Name] FROM [Double Booking]") I get a similar error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DOUBLE BOOKING
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I cannot recreate the issue with your second query. `executeQuery("SELECT [Name] FROM [Double Booking]")` works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Tom` is intended to be a string literal, you need to add quote characters:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Double Booking] WHERE [Name] = 'Tom'"
```

That said, if 'Tom' is just an example, it would be better to use a parameterised query if possible.